# Payment works but the user never knows if it was a subscription or one time payment on the Paypal page

Tags: java, paypal, payment-gateway

So I've integrated the Paypal in my payment flow and this is what happens:

- User comes on the page. Clicks the Payment Button
- User Is first redirected to a page which calls `SetExpressCheckout` and is redirected to Paypal. (He is to be billed one time for say, $77 and then every month for 1 year for the same amount. Hence I don't set the initial amount, instead deduct it directly.)
- On returning, he clicks the confirm button and one time payment is deducted using `DoExpressCheckout` and billing profile is created.

Everything works fine. I get the payment every month. The user is not billed twice at the start.

The PROBLEM: When the user was redirected to Paypal, he only sees the *ITEM NAME* and *DESCRIPTION* I've set. I.e. There is not description from Paypal whether the transaction is one time or subscription like there is when you use a simple subscription button for payment. Paypal only mentions the amount but not the type of transaction.

```java
NVPEncoder encoder = new NVPEncoder();

encoder.add("METHOD","SetExpressCheckout");
encoder.add("RETURNURL",returnURL);
encoder.add("CANCELURL",cancelURL);             
encoder.add("CURRENCYCODE","USD");
encoder.add("AMT",amt);
encoder.add("BILLINGPERIOD", "Month");
encoder.add("BILLINGFREQUENCY", "1");
encoder.add("PROFILESTARTDATE",dateFormatGmt.format(new Date()));
encoder.add("L_BILLINGTYPE0", "RecurringPayments");
encoder.add("L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0",package_name);
encoder.add("L_NAME0",package_name);
encoder.add("L_AMT0",amt);
encoder.add("L_QTY0","1");

String strNVPRequest = encoder.encode();
String ppresponse = (String) caller.call(strNVPRequest);
NVPDecoder resultValues = new NVPDecoder();
resultValues.decode(ppresponse);
String strAck = resultValues.get("ACK"); 
if (strAck !=null && !(strAck.equals("Success") || 
            strAck.equals("SuccessWithWarning"))) {
    response.sendRedirect("APIError.jsp");
} else {
    response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
}
```

Comment: You should provide examples of how you have implemented your form. I take it you have read all documentation and that you are passing the right cmd value. https://www.paypal.com/eBay/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/tech-overview-subscriptions-outside

Comment: Added the code. 

I'm using website payments pro here. I didn't try to implement the form by sending POST data to Paypal. But now that I come to think of it, does it work seamlessly and is there anything else I should know before implementing it on a membership website ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you including `L_BILLINGTYPE0=RecurringPayments`?
This is what should change the wording on the PayPal landing page.

To recap; call the following API calls, with (at least) the following parameters:

**`SetExpressCheckout`:**

```
$nvps = array();
$nvps["VERSION"] = "80.0";

$nvps["METHOD"] = "SetExpressCheckout";

$nvps["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION"] = "Sale";
$nvps["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT"] = "1.00";
$nvps["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE"] = "GBP";
$nvps["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT"] = "1.00";

$nvps["L_BILLINGTYPE0"] = 'RecurringPayments';
$nvps["L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0"] = "the subscription";

$nvps["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0"] = 1;
$nvps["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0"]= "subscription";
$nvps["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0"]= 1.00;
$nvps["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0"]= 1;
```

And **`CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile`** with:

```
$nvps["PROFILESTARTDATE"] = "2011-07-08T17:40:00Z";
$nvps["BILLINGPERIOD"] = "Month";
$nvps["BILLINGFREQUENCY"] = "1";
$nvps["AMT"] = "1.00";
$nvps["CURRENCYCODE"] = "GBP";
$nvps["DESC"] = "the subscription";
```

Comment: I have just posted my code here. 

It's in Java but I presume it shouldn't make much difference. I see you are sending more NVP than my code does. Is it because of the version of Paypal SDK I'm using ?

Comment: Also I tried sending the NVP in your post manually and I get a 10001 internal error("Timeout processing request.")